# Elasticsearch version in Grafana

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, versions

I want to use Grafana with my Elasticsearch. I am using Elasticsearch 5.X.

I have downloaded Grafana with APT and it says I have `version:master` (which doesn't help much).

In the [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/elasticsearch/#elasticsearch-version) : I should be able to use 2.X and 5.X Elasticsearch verions.

But in my admin panel when I want to create a new data source :

[image]

I only have 1.X, 2.X. Is the Grafana version coming from APT this old ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installing Grafana from [recommended APT repository](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/debian/#apt-repository) (latest version is 4.4.1) then it has 2.x and 5.x versions:

[image]

Comment: My bad, wrong configuration when I used APT. Thanks